# Trying to write a code in wix where the users cannot pick a date older than 42 days?

Tags: velo

here is the code

```
$w.onReady(function () {
  // set the minimum and maximum date for the date input field
  const dateInput = $w("#myDateField");
  const today = new Date();
  const maxDate = new Date(dateInput.valueAsDate);
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 42);
  dateInput.min = today.toISOString().split("T")[0];
  dateInput.max = maxDate.toISOString().split("T")[0];
});
```

in says max or min is not a valid property of dateInput

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not using the API correctly. Check the documentation and you'll see that

1. it's maxDate and not max
2. the value should a date not a string

https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/datepicker/maxdate